# Reusing RequestDispatcher object

Tags: java, servlets

Inside `doGet()/doPost()` in a servlet I have:

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/pages/view.jsp");
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

As the path to the jsp is not relative to current request and the `RequestDispatcher` is obtained from servlet context, can I reuse the same dispatcher object in multiple requests
such that 
`RequestDispatcher dispatcher` becomes instance variable

`init()` has

```
dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/pages/view.jsp");
```

and `doGet()/doPost()` just have

```
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

The reason behind doing so is to save the cost of construction(/lookup) of `RequestDispatcher` for every request. This may really not be significant if the server implementation already caches the objects and looks up dispatcher by the url for every `getRequestDispatcher()` call, but by obtaining the reference to dispatcher in the code in `init`, we can save the cost of lookup as well.

Also want to know if will this be thread safe as same dispatcher object will be used every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's supposed to be threadsafe, but there are certain servletcontainer makes/versions where this is not threadsafe. In Apache Tomcat for example, it was not been threadsafe until they fixed it in version 6.0.8.

I'd place this approach in the category "premature optimization". I wouldn't do it that way.